# How to insert a javascript file to my BHO Extension for IE-11? I want to insert a javascript file with multiple lines

Tags: javascript, bho

I want to insert a `javascript` into a page whenever a site loads using Browser Helper object in IE-11.

```
public void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
{
    HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;

    IHTMLElement head = (IHTMLElement)((IHTMLElementCollection)
                           document.all.tags("head")).item(null, 0);
    IHTMLScriptElement scriptObject = 
      (IHTMLScriptElement)document.createElement("script");
    scriptObject.type = @"text/javascript";

    scriptObject.text = "\nfunction hidediv(){document.getElementById" + 
                        "('myOwnUniqueId12345').style.visibility = 'hidden';}\n\n";

    ((HTMLHeadElement)head).appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)scriptObject);

    string div = "<div id=\"myOwnUniqueId12345\" style=\"position:" + 
                 "fixed;bottom:0px;right:0px;z-index:9999;width=300px;" + 
                 "height=150px;\"> <div style=\"position:relative;" + 
                 "float:right;font-size:9px;\"><a " + 
                 "href=\"javascript:hidediv();\">close</a></div>" +
        "My content goes here ...</div>";

    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("afterBegin", div);
}
```

I want to get a `javascript` file inserted into page instead of using scriptObject.text.